# Выборка по паре значений MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 списка значений: 
Например, ('red','blue','yellow','green') и ('apple','plum','banana,'kiwi').
Нужно сделать выборку в таблице по значениям ('red','apple'),('blue','plum'), ('yellow','banana'),('green','kiwi').

Приблизительно так:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE color IN ('red','blue','yellow','green') AND fruits IN ('apple','plum','banana,'kiwi');
```

Но чтобы не было ('red','plum'),('blue','apple') и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать отбор не по отдельным полям, а по их комбинации:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (color,fruits) IN (('red','apple'),
                         ('blue','plum'),
                         ('yellow','banana'),
                         ('green','kiwi'));
```

Comment: Да, спасибо,то что нужно